# How to make an application that works on both mobile and desktop web browsers?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, mobile-application

I am trying to make a web-application, which I will host on a server. It should be able to be accessed by mobile browsers on all smart phones, and also on desktop web browsers.

I am pretty new to this. Checking this out on Google is confusing me a little more, because I know I can make applications in HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript and they can be accessed on mobile browsers similarly as desktop browsers, but what I want to know is how to take care of the size and specification for the phone. The UI components should be user-friendly in mobile environment.

Is there any IDE or API that makes this possible?

Comment: I think that when you say "web-browsers" you mean "desktop browsers". "Web" refers to the world-wide-web, i.e. HTML pages accessed over HTTP. Therefore "web browsers" describes browsers running on mobile and desktop computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but what i want to know is how to take care of the size and
>   specification for the phone,

You should be using CSS media queries for that:

```
@media (max-width:480px) 
{
  // styles for devices with width 480px or less, e.g. iPhone

}
```

[MEDIA QUERIES](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Check out http://lessframework.com/ is based on @media concepts. It's small and easy to read.